# Insert text at the beginning of a text box

Tags: c#, textbox, insert

I need to insert some text as the first character of my textbox when a button is clicked.

Here is what I have tried:

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtMainView.Text.Insert(0, "TEST");
}
```

This fails to insert the text when I click the button. Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
txtMainView.Text = txtMainView.Text.Insert(0, "TEST");
```

Strings are immutable in .NET Framework so each operation creates a new instance, obviously does not change original string itself!

For more details on `String` class see MSDN page [Strings (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: For the sake of readability, you should use `txtMainView.Text = "text" + txtMainView.Text`

Comment: Yatrix already suggested this, I just pointed to the issue in original code snipped and noticed about immutability of a `String` instance.

Comment: Didn't see your answer. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

### Update for c# 6+

```
txtMainView.Text = $"TEST{txtMainView.Text}";
```

### Original

You can also go with

```
txtMainView.Text = "TEST" + txtMainView.Text;
```

as an alternative.